# how to perform both forcing https and use phprouter library using .htaccess file?

Tags: php, http, ssl, https

I forced all requests to my web by https .htaccess by the following code inside public_html.

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{SERVER_PORT} 80
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://www.yourdomain.com/$1 [R,L]
```

again phprouter library has its own default .htaccess file inside public_html.

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI}  !(\.png|\.jpg|\.webp|\.gif|\.jpeg|\.zip|\.css|\.svg|\.js|\.pdf)$
RewriteRule (.*) routes.php [QSA,L]
```

I have tried in a lot of ways but it keeps sending a page saying pages are not available. Is anyone, to help, please?